# Node modules are not exporting

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, dotenv

my node modules are not importing. I tried in export default and export const and each and every way. every each times I get either reference error or a syntax error.

**I get reference error when i update my code like below.(ReferenceError: require is not defined)**

```
const viewEngine = require( './config/viewEngine');
```

**I get syntax error when i update my code like below.(SyntaxError: The requested module './config/viewEngine' does not provide an export named 'default')**

```
import viewEngine from './config/viewEngine';
```

**I get syntax error when i update my code like below.(SyntaxError: The requested module './config/viewEngine' does not provide an export named 'viewEngine')**

```
import {viewEngine} from './config/viewEngine';
```

and the ways i tried to export:

1. `module.exports = configViewEngine;`
2. `module.exports = {configViewEngine};`

**and my dotenv is not getting defined. I tried every each ways to import dotenv too.**

**here is my package.json.**

```
{
  "name": "chatbot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon --experimental-modules --es-module-specifier-resolution=node src/server.js"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.3",
    "@babel/node": "^7.14.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "browserify": "^17.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "localtunnel": "^2.0.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "npm-upgrade": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

I use windows 10.

please help thanks!

Comment: can you post the contents of `./config/viewEngine`?

Comment: import express from "express";

let configViewEngine = (app) => {
    app.use(express.static("./src/public"));
    app.set("view engine", "ejs");
    app.set("views","./src/views");
};

module.exports = configViewEngine;

Comment: try `export default configViewEngine` instead of `module.exports = configViewEngine`. then import it using `import configViewEngine from "./config/viewEngine"`

Comment: yes thats solved. but then I get a reference error for dotenv. **(ReferenceError: require is not defined)**

Comment: i tried both ways importing dotenv.

Comment: does `import dotenv from 'dotenv'` not work?

Comment: **import dotenv from 'dotenv'** &  **const dotenv = require('dotenv').config();**

Comment: tried above both ways

Comment: what is the err you are getting?

Comment: I upgraded npm version. then it worked. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading npm version it worked.